# determining the correct xpath for following sibling

Tags: java, html, xpath

I have some html code as follows.  I am only showing the applicable part (there are more div blocks before and after but they are irrelevant here)

```
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 65px; bottom: auto; left: 5px; right: auto; width: auto; height: auto; max-width: none; max-height: none;" _afrc="2 1 6 1 start top">ID1: </div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 65px; bottom: auto; left: 89px; right: auto; width: auto; height: auto; max-width: none; max-height: none;" _afrc="3 1 6 1 start top">5134925</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 84px; bottom: auto; left: 5px; right: auto; width: auto; height: auto; max-width: none; max-height: none;" _afrc="2 1 8 1 start top">ID2: </div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 84px; bottom: auto; left: 89px; right: auto; width: auto; height: auto; max-width: none; max-height: none;" _afrc="3 1 8 1 start top">1340921</div>
```

I want to get the value of ID1 (5134925) and ID2 (1340921) and I guess I would use following sibling but I could not understand from the search.

I can use "//div[contains(text(),'ID1:')] and //div[contains(text(),'ID2:')]
but I need to find the div directly after.  I probably would use following-sibling but I can't figure the syntax.  Any suggestions?

Comment: by the way it is not really acceptable to assume a div number (like value for id2 is //div[4] because divs are always being added before and after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append `following-sibling::div[1]`:

```
//div[contains(text(),'ID1:')]/following-sibling::div[1]
```